# Bottom tab navigator show up when I click back button from my phone in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

Hi I am new in flutter and right now I try to declare my data for all tabs with this code, but when I click tab, the bottom navigator is dismiss and show up again when I click back button from my phone, is there anyone know the mistakes or the problems?

```
class BottomTab extends StatefulWidget {
final String text;
BottomTab({this.text});
  @override
  _BottomTabState createState() => _BottomTabState();
}
class _BottomTabState extends State<BottomTab> {
void initState() {
    super.initState();
   }
_onTap(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
    if (index == 0) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  new HomeScreen(value: widget.value)));
    } else if (index == 1) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  new FirstPage(value: widget.value)));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  new HomeScreen(value: widget.value)));
    }

  }
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
FirstPage(),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _index = 0;

  Widget _myList(int index) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        currentIndex: index,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.more), title: Text('More')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _myList(_index),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_index],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In your case, you do not need `Navigator.push` and change this line 
From

```
setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
```

To

```
setState(() => _index = index);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  BottomTab({this.text});
  @override
  _BottomTabState createState() => _BottomTabState();
}

class _BottomTabState extends State<BottomTab> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  _onTap(int index) {
    setState(() => _index = index);
    /*if (index == 0) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
              new HomeScreen(value: widget.value)));
    } else if (index == 1) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
              new FirstPage(value: widget.value)));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
              new HomeScreen(value: widget.value)));
    }*/
  }

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    FirstPage(),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _index = 0;

  Widget _myList(int index) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        currentIndex: index,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.more), title: Text('More')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _myList(_index),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_index],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("demo"),
        ),
        body: Text("HomesScreen"));
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("demo"),
        ),
        body: Text("FirstPage"));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BottomTab(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but from this code how I save and pass my data so that my data can be accessed within Home Tab Screen  and More Tab Screen, because my goal here is to access my data in whole tabs

Comment: You can  use the following method 1. directly put variable outside of all class 2. you can use package https://pub.dev/packages/get_it  3. you can use provider